# Returning stream from module to express route

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I'm performing different operations on a file from disk, like decrypting and unzipping. I want to send this stream as a response in my main module.

**server.js**

```
app.get('/route', function(req, res) {
  let req_params = req.query;
  cryptProvider.decrypt({file: req_params.file, key: req_params.key}).pipe(res);
})
```

**cryptProvider.js**

```
exports.decrypt = function ({ file, key }) {
  const readInitVect = fs.createReadStream(file, { end: 15 });

  let initVect;
  readInitVect.on('data', chunk => {
    initVect = chunk;
  });

  readInitVect.on('close', () => {
    const cipherKey = crypto
      .createHash('sha256')
      .update(key)
      .digest();
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(file, { start: 16 });
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes256', cipherKey, initVect);
    const unzip = zlib.createUnzip();

    return readStream
      .pipe(decipher)
      .pipe(unzip);

  })
};
```

So I'm trying to pipe `readStream` from my cryptProvider to server.js. Returning `readStream` and piping it into `res` doesn't seem to work as cryptProvider.decrypt doesn't support further piping.

I would be glad if somebody could help me figure out what's the issue here.

Comment: Pass the `res` to decrypt function and pipe it after unzip `readStream.pipe(decipher).pipe(unzip).pipe(res);` Also the reason it doesn't work is that you can't use `return` statement from within `readInitVect.on's` callback since it would `return` to its caller which is essentially `readInitVect` It's not `exports.decrypt` as you probably think.

Comment: That was really simple, I'm amazed. Thank you so much @Molda !